# Software tool for uploading code on server

Tags: c#

In our company we manually upload code on a server to make it live after testing code on a local server.

So, almost all the developers has a rights for inserting new code and updating existing code and any developer can delete/remove page or code from live.

So, I just want to keep track that which developer has inserted/updated/deleted or access the page on part of a code that is on server.

**`Is there any software available for uploading code on server ? Which keeps tracks of the user who has last access the page that is on server.`**

I want such a tool so that i can get notification that who has altered or edit code or page.

Comment: I think maybe you should look at "git" or "svn"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything that will watch for changes to files and record which user the process that made the change was running as.

This problem is usually solved by having (at the very least) a VCS (git, svn, mercurial, cvs, etc). This records who made what changes to the code.

It is common to run automatic builds on an continuous integration server (e.g. Jenkins CI).

Ideally those builds would generate an installable package (e.g. deb, rpm) that gets installed on the servers rather then code being copied up manually.

Comment: The C#-Tag looks like you want to create a msi package rather than a rpm or deb but besides that I fully agree

Comment: In my defence, the C# tag was edited into the question after I wrote the answer :)